# Error en Javascript al tratar de recorrer un objeto y por consola se muestra "undefined"

Tags: javascript, poo, bucle-for, javascript-objeto, undefined

No logro encontrar el error de por qué, si el código funciona, me pinta error en consola:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: CLIENTE is not defined
at main.js:27
```

Al parecer estoy recorriendo mal la constante CLIENTE, la cual en realidad almacenaría un objeto instanciado.

```js
function Cliente(nombreClienteParam, apellidoClienteParam, telClienteParam, mailClienteParam) {
  this.nombre = nombreClienteParam;
  this.apellido = apellidoClienteParam;
  this.tel = telClienteParam;
  this.mail = mailClienteParam;
}

document.write("<ul>");

for (let indice = 1; indice <= 3; indice++) {
  let nombre = prompt("Ingresa tu nombre");
  let apellido = prompt("Ingresa tu apellido");
  let tel = prompt("Ingresa tu telefono");
  let mail = prompt("Ingresa tu mail");

  const CLIENTE = new Cliente(nombre, apellido, tel, mail);

  document.write("<ul>");
  document.write("<li>" + CLIENTE.nombre + "</li>");
  document.write("<li>" + CLIENTE.apellido + "</li>");
  document.write("<li>" + CLIENTE.tel + "</li>");
  document.write("<li>" + CLIENTE.mail + "</li>");
  document.write("</ul>");
}

for (const propiedades in CLIENTE) {
  console.log(propiedades);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hay que cambiar el `document.write` por `document.body.appendChild`.

Si se agrega el `ul` con `write` provoca una redirección:

```
document.write ("<ul>");
```

La URL redireccionada es la siguiente:

```
wyciwyg://1/file:///...
```

Eso hace que interrumpa el script... Por eso hay que usar `appendChild` y `createElement`.

Nota: Usar `appendChild` también evita la pérdida de eventos del ratón y teclado.

Código:

```js
function Cliente(nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

var CLIENTE = new Cliente("Juan")

var ul = document.createElement("ul");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.innerHTML = CLIENTE.nombre
ul.appendChild(li)
document.body.appendChild(ul)

for(var i in CLIENTE){
  console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es que estás definiendo el objecto CLIENTE dentro del bucle `for`, utilizando `const`, por lo tanto el objeto solo existe dentro del `for`. Para solucionarlo, deberías declararlo antes.

También funcionaría si lo declaras como `var`, aunque no es una buena práctica.

Comment: Entiendo lo que me comentas @Fastigos pero eso derivaría el cambiar toda la lógica pues al sacar esa variable y tratar de mantenerla como const tampoco andarían los prompts que está dentro del for y si saco tanto la constante como las otras variables, ya no serviría de nada el for...

Comment: A lo que se refiere es a que solo saques `CLIENTE` del for y lo declares con `let`. Solo tienes que hacer una mínima modificación dentro del for -todo lo demás permanece igual- (y de hecho si lo haces el código funciona como se espera) porque efectivamente, estás obteniendo `undefined` porque el scope de `CLIENTE` no es el mismo que el que se usa para leer sus propiedades, ahí no existe `CLIENTE`. Para que tengas un mejor contexto lee acerca de los [scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Scope).

Comment: Claro, todo eso lo entiendo perfectamente @ricardo-dlc, gracias por tu explicación... pero mi reto es que se mantenga CLIENTE como una constante pero con la misma lógica del for... por eso me refería a que quizás deba plantearme otra lógica para que eso suceda pues veo imposible hacerlo tal como está.

Comment: Entonces valdria la pena, que especifíques ese detalle puesto que en tu pregunta no lo mencionas y si es algo importante para considerar tienes que especificar hasta el más mínimo detalle. Puesto a que en el segundo for solo se muestran las props de la última asignación podrías colocar algún contador que te ayude a identificar si se trata de la última iteración y entonces realizar ese segundo for dentro del primero solo cuando se trate de la última iteración. Otra opción sería guardar esos clientes en un arreglo y luego recorrer ese arreglo (o solo el último) para ver sus props.